# Strive to align item-boxes' borders vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to make flex children align vertically?

**Example**

In this case, the left "softwaredevelopment" box should increase a little so that the above "react" align with the "react" underneath. The same goes with "web", "software" and so on..? Obviously, the slight misalignment of the boxes in the picture beneath is slightly annoying...
[image]

Does a property for flexbox exist that does what I described?

**The solution should be dynamic**

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS?

Comment: flexbox can't do that - its a 1D layout - the newer CSS grid will help you, check out one of the answers below using that...

Answer (score 1):

`Flexbox` is great for horizontal layout control, but was not designed to handle vertical layout. Consider `CSS Grid` with a touch of `JavaScript` for layouts like this. Once we decide on a number of columns (7, in this case), we can add a bit of JavaScript that decides on the `span` of columns based on text length. This is a simple prototype, but could be further developed to deal with edge-case rules.

```js
let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid li");

listItems.forEach(item => {
  const len = item.innerText.length;
  if (len > 15 && len < 20) {
    item.classList.add('span-2');
  } else if (len >= 20) {
    item.classList.add('span-3');
  } // etc.
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid li {
  text-align: center;
  border: .5px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: .35em;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.full-width {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="full-width">Show all</li>
  <li>Python</li>
  <li>NodeJS</li>
  <li>React</li>
  <li>Web</li>
  <li>Software</li>
  <li>React</li>
  <li>Webdev</li>
  <li>Sofware Development</li>
  <li>React</li>
  <li>Crazy Developers</li>  
  <li>Web</li>
  <li>React</li>
  <li class="full-width">Sofware Development</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcs5ynae/6/)